# Relation between the convergence of a differentiable function and the convergence of its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Is there any relation between the convergence of a differentiable function and the convergence of its derivative?

I understand that whether $f'$ converges to zero does not tell us anything about the convergence of $f$ as there exist functions like $f_1$,
\begin{equation}
f_1(x) = \frac{\sin x^3}{x}, \quad f_{1}^{'}(x)=3x\cos x^3 -\frac{\sin x^3}{x^2}
\end{equation}
where $f_1 \to 0$ but $f_{1}^{'}$ grows unbounded and oscillates rapidly as $x\to\infty$. And there are also functions like $f_2$,
\begin{equation}
f_2(x) = \ln  x, \quad f_{2}^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{x}
\end{equation}
where $f_2 \to \infty$ but $f_{2}^{'} \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Therefore, I am curious about if there exist some additional conditions (maybe something like the Barbalat lemma?) that allow us to establish a link between the convergence of a function and the convergence of its derivative.

Comment: In general, you're developing the right intuition that the size/oscillation/limit of a function is not particularly related to the size/oscillation/limit of its derivative. One sporadic example of an implication (nontrivial but contest-math-level): if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f''(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: What is the problem with Barbalat's lemma?

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for the comment! I am actually more interested in inferring from the other way around; that is, I want to know if there is any condition that would allow me to conclude that $f(x)$ never converges to a constant if that condition together with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) \neq 0$ are satisfied.

Comment: Hi KBS, thanks for the comment! Sorry for my confusing expression; this question does not directly relate to Barbalat's lemma. I mentioned Barbalat's lemma just because I wonder if there are some additional conditions on $f''$ or on the continuity of $f$ that could allow me to find a link between the convergence of the function and the convergence of its derivative.